Is the product of all factors of an integer unique?

Given $n \in\mathbb{N}$  let $d$   the product of all the factors of $n$. Is $d$ unique to every $n$? I.e for $n\ne m$ can they have the same product of factors?

It is  easy to prove that $d$ is unique for some $n$ where for prime $p$ $n = p^m , \ n= \prod_{i}^m p_i $  where $p_i\ne p_j $ if $i \ne j$ However, I don't know how to prove it for all $n$.
I wrote a code that tested the first $3\times 10 ^5$  integers, and they all had unique
$d$.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int N = 3e5;
struct num{
  string s1;
  num(int n = 0){
    s1 = to_string(n);
  }
  void operator *=(const int n){
    string s2 = to_string(n);
    reverse(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    reverse(s2.begin() , s2.end()); 
    int MXN = 2 * max(s1.size() , s2.size())+ 9;
    vector<int> a(MXN);
    for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<s2.length(); j++) {
            a[i + j] += (s1[i]-'0') * (s2[j] - '0');
        }
    }
      for (int i=0; i< MXN - 1; i++) {
            a[i + 1] += a[i] / 10;
            a[i] %= 10;
      }
      int i = MXN - 1;
      while (i > 0 && a[i] == 0) i--;
      s1 = "";
      for (; i>=0; i--) s1 += char(a[i] + '0');
  }
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const num& obj) {
    for(auto &ch : obj.s1){
        os << ch;
    }
    return os;
  }
  bool operator <(const num &other) const{ return s1 < other.s1; }  
  bool operator ==(const num &other) const{ return s1 == other.s1; }    
} mul[N + 1]; 
int main(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) mul[i] = 1;
    // For each i [1..N], find multiplication of all divisors of i
    for(int i = 2; i <= N; ++i){
        for(int j = i; j <= N; j += i)
            mul[j] *= i;
    }
    // check
    map<num , int> mp;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i){
        if( mp.count(mul[i]) ){
            cout << "Counter example:\n";
            cout << "num1: " << mp[mul[i]] << ", num2: " << i << '\n';
            cout << "D: " << mul[i] << '\n';
        }else mp[mul[i]] = i;
    }
    cout << "Finish";
}

Another question is: If this hypothesis is not true for all  $n$, what conditions should $n$ fulfill so that there is a unique
$d$ for it?

Not quite clear : Of course , the factors of a number and therefore its product are determined and hence unique. Do you mean that no other number has the same product of factors ?

Apparently this is https://oeis.org/A007955. First comment: “All terms of this sequence occur only once.” Reference: http://www.sspectra.com/math/DivisorProduct.pdf

@MartinR I suggest to work this out as an answer , but please self-contained and not dependent on the pdf-link.

Puzzled here.  Are you looking at the product of factors ignoring their multiplicity?  $6$ has the factors $2$ and $3$ but $12$ has the same factors.

@badjohn Apparently , here all factors are considered , not just the prime factors. Divisor would be a better terminology , I think.

@Peter Thanks. I guessed that I was missing something but I didn't want to reverse engineer that code.

@Peter: Done :)

Do you think the set of factors can have two different products?

Okay.....
so if $n = \prod p_i^{a_i}$ (which is product unique to $n$) then the set of divisors is $S= \{\prod p_i^{b_i}|0\le b_i \le a_i\}$  and the product of all divisors of $n$ is....
$\prod p_i^{S_i}$ where...
each $S_i = (\sum_{k=1}^{a_i} k)(\prod_{j\ne i}(1+a_j))=$
$\frac {a_i(a_i+1)}2 (\prod_{j\ne i}(1+a_j))=$
$\frac {a_i}2 (1+a_i)(\prod_{j\ne i}(1+a_j))=\frac{a_i}2 \prod(1+a_j)$
Why does each $S_i = (\sum_{k=1}^{a_i} k)(\prod_{j\ne i}(1+a_j))$?
Well, how often will to prime $p_i$ appear in the product?  (Bear with me).  $n = p_i^{a_k}\times \prod_{j\ne i}p_j^{a_j}$.  Let $D = \prod_{j\ne i}p_j^{a_j}$.  The prime $p_i$ will appear in divisors of the form $p_i^k d$ where $1\le k \le a_i$ and $d|D$.  So the $p_i$ will appear $k$ times for each $p_i^k d$ or $k\times |number\ of\ divisors\ of\ D|$. And $p_i$ will appear $(1+ 2+ 3+ .... + k + ....+a_1)|number\ of\ divisors\ of\ d|$ times total.
So $S_i = (\sum_{k=1}^{a_i} k)|number\ of\ divisors\ of\ D|$.
But what is $|number\ of\ divisors\ of\ D|$?
Well $D=\prod{j\ne i} p_j^{a_j}$ so each divisor $d$ of $D$ is of the form $\prod_{j\ne i} p_j^{b_j}$ where $0 \le b_j \le a_j$.  For each $a_j$ there are $1+a_j$ chooses for the value of $b_j$, so the there are $\prod_{j\ne i}(1+a_j)$ possible divisors of the form $\prod_{j\ne i} p_j^{b_j}$.  So $|number\ of\ divisors\ of\ D| = \prod_{j\ne i}(1+a_j)$
As so $S_i = (\sum_{k=1}^{a_i} k)(\prod_{j\ne i}(1+a_j))=\frac{a_i}2 \prod(1+a_j)$
....
Okay, so that's the major hurdle.
If product of all the divisors of $m$ is equal to the product of all the divisors of $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ the $m$ must have the exact same prime factors fo $m$.  So $m =\prod p_i^{c_i}$ for some natural $c_i$s.
Ad we must have that each $S_i =\frac{a_i}2 \prod(1+a_j) =\frac {c_i}2\prod(1+c_j)$.
Let $\prod(1+a_j) = K$, a constant value and $\prod(1+c_j) =J$, also a constant.
The each $c_i = a_i \times \frac KJ$.
If $\frac KJ < 1$ then each $c_i < a_i$ and then $J = \prod (1+c_j) < \prod (1+a_j)=K$ and $\frac KJ > 1$.  That's a contradiction, as is assuming $\frac KJ > 1$.
So $\frac KJ = 1$ and $\prod (1+a_j) = \prod (1+c_j)$ and $a_i = c_i$ for all $a_i$.
So $m = \prod p_i^{a_i} =n$, and the products are all unique.
======
Post-edit.
Oh, for the love of goop.  I was not aware of this result Product of Divisors of some $n$ proof which pretty much makes this answer a duplicate.
But this answer I have: Product of divisors of $n = \prod p_i^{S_i}$ where $S_i$ is $\frac {a_i}2\prod(1+a_j)$ can be more eloquently written as
Product of divisors of $n = \prod p_i^{\frac {a_i}2\prod(1+a_j)}=$
$(\prod p_i^{a_i})^{\frac {\prod(1+a_j)}2}=n^{\frac {d(n)}2}$
where $d(n)=\prod (1+a_j) = $ the number of divisors of $n$.
That certainly seems a more intuitive, graceful, and informative way or writing it.
The argument they must be unique might be less obvious though:
If $n^{\frac {d(n)}2} = m^{\frac {d(m}2}$ then
$n = m^{\frac {d(m)}{d(n)}}$.
$n$ and $m$ have the same prime factors.  If $n > m$ then it's intuitive that $n$ will have overall more prime factors contradicting that the $\frac{d(m)}{d(n)}$ would have to be less than $1$.  But  can we really claim $n$ being larger than $m$ must mean $d(n) > d(m)$?
$n$ must have a prime factor with a higher power than $m$ does but maybe that prime is large and all the other factors are lower so the overall effect could be $n>m$ but $d(n) < d(m)$; would that be possible? We'd need an argument that each individual power, and not just the overall product of one more than the powers, must also be proportional.
But still.... I really didn't need to replicate the same argument to get a known result.... oh, well.

That's not the product of all divisors of $n$ though: The power of $p_i$ in the product of all factors will be $(a_i(a_i + 1)/2) \times (\prod_{j \neq i} (1 + a_j))$

Oh... oops.  I'll edit this in in.... several hours.  That's was a foolish oversight.  And not that trivial.

That is A007955 from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®:

A007955 Product of divisors of n.

where it is said that

All terms of this sequence occur only once.

with a reference to T. D. Noe, The Divisor Product is Unique.
The following proof is taken from that article. I will also use the same notation:

$d(n) = $ number of divisors of $n$,
$\pi(n) = $ product of the divisors of $n$.

First note that
$$ \tag 1
 \pi(n) = n^{d(n)/2} \, ,
$$
see for example Product of Divisors of some $n$ proof.
Now assume that $n > m$ with $\pi(n) = \pi(m)$. Using $(1)$ it follows that
$$ \tag 2
 n = m^{d(m)/d(n)}
$$
and therefore
$$ \tag 3
 d(m) > d(n) \, .
$$
Since $n$ and $m$ necessarily have the same prime factors we can write their factorization as
$$
 n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k} \, ,\\
 m = p_1^{f_1} p_2^{f_2} \cdots p_k^{f_k} 
$$
with positive exponents $e_i$ and $f_i$. From equation $(2)$ it follows that
$$ \tag 4
 e_i = \frac{d(m)}{d(n)} f_i > f_i
$$
for $1 \le i \le k$.
It is well-known that the number of divisors can be computed from the prime factorization, see for example Prove a property of divisor function :
$$
 d(n) = (1+e_1)(1+e_2) \cdots (1+e_k) \, ,\\
 d(m) = (1+f_1)(1+f_2) \cdots (1+f_k) \, .
$$
Using $(4)$ it follows $d(n) > d(m)$ and that is a contradiction to $(3)$.
